# JAVA Cant find subclass method via cast

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, subclass, superclass

I have this problem with my homework and I can't seem to find on the Internet for a solution.

I have a superclass and its subclass. In a different class i have to use as parameter the superclass in a method however i need a method in the subclass but the compiler cant find it if i cast the superclass.
My code looks like smthing like this:

```
public class A{...}

public class B extends A{
...
public boolean methodX(){...}
}

public class DifferentClass{

public void methodY(A a){
if(a instanceof B){
(B)a.methodX();
}
}
}
```

I get the error cant find symbol, however this is the way i have to construct my classes and methods as the teacher told us(have to be a super class, a subclass with a method in it, and a method in a different class with the given parameter of superclass).

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

`.` has a higher precedence than a cast. Hence, you need another set of parenthesis:

```
((B) a).methodX();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your cast is wrong, it should be `((B) a).methodX()`

Comment: ohh jesus.. such a silly mistake, thank you very much